# What is the significance of the equation (a+b)^2?

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the use of the equation (a+b)<sup>2</sup> in real life? How is it related to day to day life. I can't learn maths until I can connect it to real life. Can you give me an easy explanation of it's significance from real life perspective. Thank you.

Comment: $(a+b)^2$ is the area of a square with sides $a+b$

Comment: That's not an equation, its a simple algebraic expression. I have seen it pop up in a proof of pythagoras' theorem, where you consider a square with sides $a+b$. But learning maths at that level is more about just learning the tools and how to manipulate them - you then do more with more complicated algebra later in applied maths.

Comment: You say that $(a + b)^2$ is an *equation*. An equation is a pair of expressions or terms separated by an equals sign. For instance, $58n^2 + 1$ is not an equation because where is the equals sign? It doesn’t exist. But then when we say $58n^2 + 1 = p$, since the equals sign is existent, it is an *equation*. The word *equals* derives from the word *equation*. Now if we let $p$ equal some value, we can solve for $n$. I suggest that if you want to incorporate mathematics into a real life perspective, you should firstly understand a little more about the concept and terminology of mathematics.

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a basic fact of algebraic manipulation, and any engineer or scientist or anyone working with algebra will end up using it in any of their real life applications.

How about this though? You have a yard, and in the yard you have a square veggie patch. It's 10 meters long on one side. You wanna expand it, so you make one side 5 meters longer. But you want to preserve the square shape, so you make it into a square that is 15 meters long on a side. The area was originally $100$ $m^2$, but now how much is it? Using the formula $(a+b)^2$ could help!

---

**Advanced material**

Now here's an interesting one that engineers often face a lot. Instead of expanding each side by 5 meters, you decide to expand each side by 0.1 meters (let's say you only need enough extra area to grow an extra row of flowers). Now you want to use the formula $(a+b)^2$, but lets say for reasons you don't want to do all the math (and these reasons are actually more common than you think). Notice that the formula says $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 = 10^2 + 2*10*0.1 + 0.1^2$. Knowing this algebraic expression, we can reason that BECAUSE 0.1 is small compared to 10, we can get a really close estimate of the correct area by ignoring the term $0.1^2$. So the estimate for the area is $a^2+2ab = 10^2 + 2*10*0.1$. This shows up a LOT in engineering and physics calculations and approximations (the *first-order* approximation) and relies entirely on this algebraic expression!

Answer (score 4):

$(a+b)^2$ isn't an equation -- it's just a term.

How it connects to "day to day life" depends on what your day-to-day life is like. But here's one application. You have a square-shaped bathroom with a square-shaped shower in the corner. You know the distance from the wall to the shower is  $a$ and the length of the shower is $b$. The area of the room -- which you need to know because you need to tile the floor, or something like that -- is $(a+b)^2$

Comment: Is $(a + b)^2$ a *term*? We can re-write this as $a^2 + b^2 + 2ab$ which is now an *expression*....